# Oracle : SUM Column of only duplicates row exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database view X with the following structure

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "TESTVIEW"."VW_SUM__DOCUMENTS" ( "DOCUMENT_NUM", "AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT  
    vw_container_documents.document_num,
    vw_container_documents.amount AS amount
   FROM vw_container_documents
  WHERE vw_container_documents.parent_id IS NOT NULL
```

This is the results of this view :

```
document_num    |amount
-----------------------
25    |1 
25    |1
23    |2
25    |2
```

I want to change this view in away to retrieve values without duplicated (doing sum of duplicate amount)
and give this results :

```
document_num    |amount
-----------------------
25    |4 
23    |2
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're looking for is a Group By statement. As such:

```
Select document_num, sum(amount)
  from "TESTVIEW"."VW_SUM__DOCUMENTS"
  group by document_num;
```